# javascript patch an existing external dependency module method with a mocked version in unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm looking for something like this in python: http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/04/10/using-the-python-mock-library-to-fake-regular-functions-during-tests/

but for javascript/node.js to mock out a class method, or non-class method, etc. used inside code to be tested, like a black box, e.g. external dependencies. Is there something currently available for node.js like that? Or how to emulate that python unit test behavior? I'm currently using mocha & chai for node.js unit testing. Here's example of the intended test to illustrate:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect; // we are using the "expect" style of Chai
//SUT module inherits/extends BasicBolt from: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/javascript/src/main/resources/resources/storm.js
var SUT = require('./../my_code_under_test.js');
var storm = require("./../storm.js");
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

//...

  it('component tests my code, somewhat like a black box', function() {
    var myBolt = new SUT.MyCustomBolt();
    var cfg = {}, context = {}, done = function() { return; };
    myBolt.initialize(cfg,context,done);
    var input = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "input/data.json"),{'encoding':'utf8'});
    var tup = new storm.Tuple(1,"default","default",1,["foo",input]);
    myBolt.process(tup,done);
    //myBolt.process makes HTTP GET call via node.js sync-request module
    //myBolt.process then ends by calling a "self.emit()", e.g. BasicBolt.emit()
    //for testing purposes, need to mock out request('GET',url) from sync-request, so not need HTTP endpoint to return result
    //and need to mock emit such that it simply stores a copy of the emitted data to a (global) variable we can assert against, then reset the variable at end of each test. myBolt.process() itself does not return data to assert against.
    expect(theEmittedData).to.equal('some value');
  });

//...
```

I was able to do this approach in python, using the referenced link. I hope can do same in javascript. Or is the javascript best practice done differently?

FYI, am writing tests to test the code without having to run it within Apache Storm topology/infrastructure, just with the client libraries. As the bolt is rather simple, doesn't make sense to try to break down further the code inside myBolt.process() just to avoid having to mock the external dependencies, and I want to test around/with the storm library it's coupled with.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 libraries you should consider would be [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) and [testdouble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testdouble).

Comment: Thanks, that's a start for me.

Comment: I updated my question, would you be able to give advice beyond the link references to javascript mocking libraries? I looked over their docs, but haven't figured out exactly how to implement what I want. It's not as clear cut (or as easy to use) as the python link.